# Resize PictureBox width and keep aspect ratio

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, picturebox, aspect-ratio

I'm loading the image dynamically to a pre-existing PictureBox `person_img` that has all default values and is not sized correctly. I'm expecting to be able to do the sizing dynamically so that all images are 1/3 of `people_popup_tab` width.

I've tried many ways, including answers from similar questions. My last attempt was to load the image and set the SizeMode to AutoSize so that it would first get rendered at its full size, then I'd be able to get its width and height this way. Then I would use this width and height to know how to proportionately scale the image down.

But the image still renders all wonky. Some also simply don't show up now.

[image]

How can I resize the image to 1/3 of `people_popup_tab` width without losing aspect ratio?

My current code:

```
person_img.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
person_img.Load(thisFaculty.imagePath);
int oldWidth = person_img.Width; 
int oldHeight = person_img.Height;
int newWidth = people_popup_tab.Width / 3;
int newHeight = oldHeight * (newWidth / oldWidth);
person_img.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
person_img.Width = newWidth;
person_img.Height = newHeight;
```

Comment: First load the image to Bitmap class, resize it (or get the real width/height) and than assign to picturebox

Comment: I've never heard of the Bitmap class. I will try to find out how. My image is from an URL

Comment: I added an asnwer

Comment: You may want to actually look into what options are available in that `SizeMode` enum...

Answer (score 0):

First load the image to Bitmap class, than resize your picture box using the real dimensions of the image. Similar to below code

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(imageFile);
pictureBox1.Width = bmp.Width / 3;
pictureBox1.Height = bmp.Height / 3;
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Comment: I think  `pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom` would help in keeping the PictureBox the same size while maintaining the bitmap proportions. -- Assigning the bitmap this way: `pictureBox1.Image = bmp;`, GDI+ will lock the file. `pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(bmp);` can solve this.